# Memory issue with camel resequencer

Tags: memory-leaks, apache-camel, jms, thread-priority

I have a `camel` resequencer for giving priorities to the incoming messages.

```
from(fromLocation)
        .routeId(routeName)
        .autoStartup(true)
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .threads(1)
        .setHeader(PRIORITY, constant(1))
        .to(SEDA_PROCESS_NOTIFICATIONS+id);

from(SEDA_PROCESS_NOTIFICATIONS+id) 
        .resequence(header(PRIORITY))
        .allowDuplicates
from(endpoint2)
   .setHeader(PRIORITY, constant(2))
   .to(SEDA_PROCESS_NOTIFICATIONS+id);
```

However, after running this for some 3-4 hours, I get `memory exception` with the `batchprocessor` of Resequencer. The `batchProcessor` is not releasing the memory. The error persists even if I try to decrease the batch size. If I use stream mode of resequencer, then all the messages are not processed. Please let me know what am I missing here?